# ngx-translate does not load JSON file when deployed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-app-engine, ngx-translate

I have implemented the localization of my the App I am working on using `ngx-translate`. Everything's been working fine until it got deployed in App Engine. I am getting the following errors and the website is full of the translation keys.

[image: error]

I am aware this happens because the application is unable to find the JSON files and therefore it uses the `index.html` by default but I fail to understand why the JSON files are not found.

This is my project organization:

[image: organization]

This is my `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        XXXXXX
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CarouselModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            defaultLanguage: 'en',
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateHttpLoader,
                useFactory: translateHttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpBackend]
            }
        })
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: JWT_OPTIONS, useValue: JWT_OPTIONS },
        JwtHelperService, SellerserviceService,
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpRequestInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor, multi: true }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent], }) 
    export class AppModule { }

export function translateHttpLoaderFactory(httpBackend: HttpBackend): TranslateHttpLoader {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(new HttpClient(httpBackend), 'assets/i18n', '.json'); }
```

Regarding `translateHttpLoaderFactory` I have tried different combinatios for the suffix such as `./assets/i18n`, `/assets/i18n` and `/assets/i18n/`
I previously had `HttpClient` instead of `HttpBackend` because I read interceptors may be causing issues but it's still the same behaviour.

This is the build section of my `angular.json`:

```
"build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/untitled",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": true,
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/assets/i18n"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
                            "./node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.carousel.min.css",
                            "./node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.theme.default.min.css",
                            "src/styles.css",
                            "src/dmg-styles.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "src/dmg-scripts.js"
                        ]
                    },
```

And these are the dependencies I am using in `package.json`

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
```

My Angular version is 10.

### Edit 1

I have added a missing forward slash in `translateHttpLoaderFactory` but the error persists.

[image: error-2]

### Edit 2

This is my `app.yml`

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
  - url: /favicon.ico
    static_files: dist/untitled/favicon.ico
    upload: dist/untitled/favicon.ico
  - url: /favicon.png
    static_files: dist/untitled/favicon\.png
    upload: dist/untitled/favicon\.png

  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js)(|\.map))$
    static_files: dist/untitled/\1
    upload: dist/untitled/(.*)(|\.map)

  - url: /(.*)
    static_files: dist/untitled/index.html
    upload: dist/untitled/index.html

skip_files:
  - e2e/
  - node_modules/
  - src/
  - ^(.*/)?\..*$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.json$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.md$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.yaml$
  - ^LICENSE
```

Comment: As seen from the screenshot, it appears the app is trying to load `/assets/i18nen.json` which obviously isn't available. It seems to be missing a forward slash after `i18n`.

Comment: @MichaelD yeah, I was missing that but I added the right slash and it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: You are deploying this to app engine so you must have a app.yaml in your project, right? Can you share it's contents?

Comment: @RafaelLemos I have just added the `app.yml`

Comment: hello, by navigating to your website url "https://dmdlegtek.uc.r.appspot.com/assets/i18nen.json" , your file is not found on your server. so your solution will be to check first how do you deploy your app and check if your json file exists in your server or not (through dist folder) , if yes then check your .htaccess and rewrite mod configuration in your server.

Comment: by the way i have a doub about your file name "i18nen.json", i think it should be "i18n/en.json" instead..

Comment: I think the issue is that you don't have json in your generic mapping on the yaml, that is why is not mapped, try adding json to this line in the yaml and let me know if it fixed: `url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|json)(|\.map))$`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you did not map `.json` files in your generic file extension mapping in the yaml file, because of that your app is not able to find the files. To fix it, all you need to do is add the `.json` to your generic mapping like this:

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|json)(|\.map))$
  static_files: dist/untitled/\1
  upload: dist/untitled/(.*)(|\.map)
```